# Social network datasets

Tags: classification, dataset

I am looking for social network datasets (twitter, friendfeed, facebook, lastfm, etc.) for classification tasks, preferably in arff format.

My searches via UCI and Google weren't successful so far... any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Check out the Stanford large network dataset collection: [SNAP](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/).

Answer (score 6):

- [A huge twitter dataset that includes followers, not just tweets](http://blog.infochimps.com/2008/12/29/massive-scrape-of-twitters-friend-graph/)
- [large collection of twitter datasets here](http://infochimps.com/collections/twitter-census)

Answer (score 3):

A large index of facebook pages was created and is available as a torrent (It is ~2.8Gb) http://btjunkie.org/torrent/Facebook-directory-personal-details-for-100-million-users/3979e54c73099d291605e7579b90838c2cd86a8e9575

Twitter datasets are tagged on Infochimps: http://infochimps.com/tags/twitter

A lastfm dataset is available at http://mtg.upf.edu/node/1671

Answer (score 3):

visit the Max Planck institute. They have also collected several datasets for OSNs.

Comment: link: http://socialnetworks.mpi-sws.org/

Answer (score 2):

Just found this: [476 million Twitter tweets](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/twitter7.html) (via [@yarapavan](https://twitter.com/#!/yarapavan)).

Answer (score 2):

We have curated a Twitter dataset for friends of users in 2009 and then in 2009. You can find more information here: http://strict.dista.uninsubria.it/?p=364

Answer (score 1):

A good resource for finding datasets is:

[/r/datasets](http://datasets.reddit.com) on Reddit.

A quick glance at that page reveals [this source](http://networkdata.ics.uci.edu/resources.php), which might contain something useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out kaggle.com , they have some contests about social networks and they give out datasets.

Also, Stanford's SNAP is a great resource. And it has research works to boot.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook social graph, application installations and Last.fm users, events, groups at
http://odysseas.calit2.uci.edu/research/

Two datasets (collected April-May 2009) which contain representative samples of ~1 million users Facebook-wide, with a few annotated properties: for each sampled user,  the friend list, privacy settings, and network membership are included. A third dataset ( collected Feb 2008) includes a bipartite graph that represents application installations by Facebook users. A fourth dataset with Daily Active Users and application installations over 6 months (collected Sept 2007-Feb 2008). A fifth dataset that includes a representative sample of Last.fm users obtained using multigraph sampling (collected July 2010).

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2166) uses a [facebook dataset](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/~porterm/data/facebook100.zip) that is available here. Here is the description from the authors:

> The data includes the complete set of nodes and links (and some
>   demographic information) from **100** US colleges and universities from a
>   single-time snapshot in September 2005.