# Where can I get real data of big network topology?

Tags: networks, topologies

I want to model how traffic will flow on real networks (not just the internet, also, say, Intel's internal LAN).

Is there a place I can get real network topologies data I can use?

Comment: http://getthedata.org/ bills itself as a question and answer site for finding data

Comment: @Jeromy thanks, posted http://getthedata.org/questions/399/where-can-i-get-real-data-of-big-network-topology

Comment: A question when you say "network" - that word means many things. Do you mean anything that might be defined as a network (for example, the social contacts of an entire city) or do you mean a network of computers?

Comment: @EpiGrad indeed a network of computers. LAN, or WAN, etc.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the source listed by JohnRos, the association for social network analysis ([INSNA](http://www.insna.org/software/data.html)) have a lot of data (sometimes the datasets are missing, though).
Another source might be [Tore Opsahl's website](http://toreopsahl.com/datasets/) (the airline data are a good candidate, as the forum data are). Finally, [Mark Newman's page](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/netdata/) is another source.
If you have an interest in open source software, [FLOSSmole](http://flossmole.org/) might be another place to fish for large network datasets (but I do not know if there is information about flow in there).
This [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4451/social-network-datasets) gives a lot of other potential sources

Answer (score 0):

[Stanford Large Network Dataset Collection](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/). Which is part of the Stanford Network Analysis Project, SNAP.

Comment: Can you point me, which of the dataset there relates to network (eg ethernet, LAN, WAN) topology? I don't see anything there.

Comment: @Elazar: SNAP is a *wonderful* resource, but the reason you don't find any such data sets there is because there aren't any. (There are a few web graphs. The [autonomous systems](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/index.html#as) ones may come close, but I suspect not quite what you're looking for.)